# How to access unsub reason?

Tags: unsubscribe

I am working on a task to query unsub reason in Query Activity. I am trying to query this field 'Unsubscribe Reason' shown in SS below in the right box. The filed is present in Email Studio All Subscribers Search.

This field is not available in _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes data view.

Any advice?

[image: unsub reason]